# Multithreaded (or async) calculation on Spring Framework

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, spring-mvc, asynchronous

I am learning Spring Framework, and it is pretty awesome.

I want to use JAVA multithreading, but I don't know how with the Spring Framework.

Here is the code for service:

```
//StudentService.java
public List<Grade> loadGradesForAllStudents(Date date) {
    try{
        List<Grade> grades = new ArrayList<Grade>();
        List<Student> students = loadCurrentStudents(); // LOAD FROM THE DB

        for(Student student : students) { // I WANT TO USE MULTITHREAD FOR THIS PART

            // LOAD FROM DB (MANY JOINS)
            History studentHistory = loadStudentHistory(student.getStudentId(), date); 

            // CALCULATION PART
            Grade calculatedGrade = calcStudentGrade(studentHistory, date);

            grades.add(calculatedGrade);
        }
        return grades;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        ...
        return null;
    }
}
```

And without multithreading, it is pretty slow.

I guess the for loop causes the slowness, but I don't know how to approach this problem.  If give me an useful link or example code, I'd appreciate it.

I figured out the method loadStudentHistory is pretty slow (around 300ms) compare to calcStudentGrade (around 30ms).

Comment: any reason you want to do this via spring? this can be done without Spring

Comment: Your bottleneck is in the query. Executing more queries at the same time will not fix your problem, but maybe make it even worse. Also, this has nothing to do with Spring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using multithreading for this a bad idea in an application with concurrent users, because instead of having each request use one thread and one connection now each query uses multiple threads and multiple connections. It doesn't scale as the number of users grows.

When I look at your example I see two possible issues:

1) You have too many round trips between the application and the database, where each of those trips takes time.

2) It's not clear if each query is using a separate transaction (you don't say where the transactions are demarcated in the example code), if your queries are each creating their own transaction that could be wasteful, because each transaction has overhead associated with it.

Using multithreading will not do much to help with #1 (and if it does help it will put more load on the database) and will either have no effect on #2 or make it worse (depending on the current transaction scopes; if you had the queries in the same transaction before, using multiple threads they'll have to be in different transactions). And as already explained it won't scale up.

My recommendations:

1) Make the service transactional, if it is not already, so that everything it does is within one transaction. Remove the exception-catching/null-returning stuff (which interferes with how Spring wants to use exceptions to rollback transactions) and introduce an exception-handler so that anything thrown from controllers will be caught and logged. That will minimize your overhead from creating transactions and make your exception-handling cleaner.

2) Create one query that brings back a list of your students. That way the query is sent to the database once, then the resultset results are read back in chunks (according to the fetch size on the resultset). You can customize the query to get back only what you need so you don't have an excessive number of joins. Run explain-plan on the query and make sure it uses indexes. You will have a faster query and a much smaller number of round trips, which will make a big speed improvement.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is called [stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html), these enable you to iterate in [parallel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html), for example :

```
students.stream().parallel().forEach( student -> doSomething(student));
```

This **will** give you a noticeable performance-boost **but** it wont remove the database-query overhead ... if your DB-management system takes about 300ms to return results .... well ... you're either using ORM on **big** databases or your queries are highly inefficient, i recommend re-analyzing your current solution

Comment: Oh no I'm using JDK 7 :(

Comment: well install JDK8 then .... its not like java is (actually) bound to JDK-releases.

Comment: Oh well, I can't install it now.  Is there any other option? Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: you can also segment the data-field, create a sensible amounf of threads and let each thread process at least one segment ... i recommend keeping the amount of threads to your number of available  CPU-cores -- 4 or 8 in most cases. Maybe try accessing the same, thread-safe collection via numeric indexes which run from the begin of one segment to its end - that way you will avoid having to iterate the whole collection one full time before you start the threads.

Comment: apparently : http://www.journaldev.com/1061/java-synchronization-and-thread-safety-tutorial-with-examples

As you can see, not using JDK8 has major drawbacks nowadays - it adds quite some complexity **and** will make you run into mistakes.

Comment: hes ... still with us. Lets all hope he stays for a few more decades, he created a truly marvelous language.